# android webview and html webpage with script to display images

Tags: java, android, upload

before i post the code let me explain what i intended to do, the webview loads a html page that has a form to upload images, when i select one image it display it perfectly and i even added the file count and it shows 1, but now when i select multiple images the file count 0 and it does not display the images

here is the android PostFragment java code

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log; // Import the Log class
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

public class PostFragment extends Fragment {
private WebView webView;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUploadMessage;
private static final int FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 123; // Define your permission     request code

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post, container, false);
    webView = view.findViewById(R.id.WebViewIdpost);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Add the JavaScript interface here
    JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(getActivity());
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "Android");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    // Set up WebChromeClient with console message logging
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams     fileChooserParams) {
            mUploadMessage = filePathCallback;
            openFileChooser();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
            // Log console messages for debugging
            Log.d("WebView Console", consoleMessage.message());
            return true;
        }


        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            // Handle web view errors
            Log.e("WebView Error", "Error code: " + errorCode + ", Description: " + description);
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("this is where i put the url"); // Change the URL to the location of your HTML form

    return view;
}

private void openFileChooser() {
    // Check if the permission is granted
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // If permission is not granted, request it
        requestPermission();
    } else {
        // Permission is already granted, open the file chooser
        openFilePicker();
    }
}

private void requestPermission() {
    // Request permission from the user
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(),
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission granted, open the file chooser
            openFilePicker();
        } else {
            // Permission denied, handle the case where the user refuses permission
            // You might want to display a message to the user
            Log.e("Permission Error", "Permission denied for accessing external storage.");
        }
    }
}

private void openFilePicker() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true); // Allow multiple file selection
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose File"), FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE) {
        if (mUploadMessage == null) {
            return;
        }
        Uri[] results = WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, data);
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(results);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
    }
}
```

here is the html page with script

```
<script>
function displaySelectedImages(files) {
    var preview = document.getElementById('imagePreview');

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
       
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = e.target.result;
                preview.appendChild(img);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        
    }

    // Display the number of selected files
    var fileCountText = document.getElementById('fileCountText');
    fileCountText.textContent = 'Number of selected files: ' + files.length;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="cgi-bin/upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"     id="uploadForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_codex" id="item_codex" value="<?PHP echo $item_codex?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_mycode" id="item_mycode" value="<?PHP echo $item_mycode?>">
    <input type="file" name="images[]" id="images" multiple="multiple"  onchange="displaySelectedImages(this.files)">
   <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Upload Images">
</form>

<div id="imagePreview"></div>
<div id="fileCountText"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

i have been fighting with this for hours, i got it to where it shows one image when i select one, but when i select multiple it does not show multiple images

i gave up so i appreciate all the help you can spare

Comment: `html page that has a form to upload images, ` Ok. To where? And where came that page from?

Comment: `when i select one image it display it perfectly` Display? You said you wanna upload. Where would display come in?